# How do I get the Age data from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Parent.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

const Parent = () => {
    const[data,setData] = useState('')
    const[name,setName] = useState('')
    const[toggled,setToggled] = useState(false)
    const[age,setAge] = useState('')

    const ageToChild = (ageData) =>{
        setAge(ageData)
    }
    const childToParent = (childData) =>{
        setData(childData)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        alert(`Age is ${age} , Form Submitted`)
        console.log(`Name is ${name} and Age is ${age}`)
    }
  return (
    <>
        {data}
        <div>
            {/* <Child childToParent={childToParent}></Child> */}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Name : </label>
                <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}></input>
                <button type='button' onClick={()=>setToggled(!toggled)}>Age ?</button>
                {toggled && <Child childToParent={childToParent} ageToChild={ageToChild}></Child>}
                <button type='button'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Parent
```

Child.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Child = ({childToParent,ageToChild}) => {
    const data = "This is some data from the child component to parent"
    // const age = ageToChild
  return (
    <>
        <button onClick={()=>childToParent(data)}>Click Child</button>
        <label>Age : </label>
        <input type='text' onChange={()=>ageToChild()}></input>
    </>
  )
}

export default Child
```

I am getting output as Name is *inputtedname* and Age is Undefined , How do I get the user inputted age value logged in the console?
I am trying to pass data from child to parent using functional components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass age value to alert() from Child.js component, you should add `e.target.value` to `onChange`:

```
<input type='text' onChange={(e)=>ageToChild(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
<input type='text' onChange={(e)=>ageToChild(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to pass the `ageToChild` function from the parent component to the child:

```
<Child childToParent={childToParent} ageToChild={ageToChild} />
```

Then from the `Child` component you can simply do:

```
<input type='text' onChange={(e)=> ageToChild(e.target.value)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to pass the value in the function. Try passing it in `onChange`.

```
onChange={(e)=>ageToChild(e.target.value)}
```